# Is there something like AC_CHECK_LIB for python setup.py build instructions?

Tags: python, gcc, autoconf, iconv

I have a python package that builds its own extension module.  currently I'm doing all the compilation in setup.py as an ext_module, but I really need AC_CHECK_LIB type capability - is there something like this for setup.py, or do I need to write a autoconf for my module?

Specific case here is that quite a few distros now have iconv included in libc, but I still need to support distros where -liconv needs to be passed to gcc.  How can I check if iconv functionality is included in libc or not?

Should I skip doing all this through setup.py, and use autoconf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my poking around, it doesn't look like there's much you can do. You might have luck using `autoconf` to generate `setup.py`, or you could use `automake` and `libtool` and do the whole thing with autofoo. Automake provides a macro `AM_PATH_PYTHON` that sets a whole pile of useful variables and gives the following example for declaring an extension module:

```
pyexec_LTLIBRARIES = quaternion.la
quaternion_la_SOURCES = quaternion.c support.c support.h
quaternion_la_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -module
```

Comment: the problem is, I don't know if I need that library.  arg.

Comment: That's what `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` is for, checking if something works without any libraries, then checking for a lib: http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/Libraries.html